# AWS ECS does not drain connections or remove tasks from Target Group before stopping them

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, devops, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I've been experiencing this with my ECS service for a few months now. Previously, when we would update the service with a new task definition, it would perform the rolling update correctly, deregistering them from the target group and draining all http connections to the old tasks before eventually stopping them. However, lately ECS is going straight to stopping the old tasks *before* draining connections or removing them from the target group. This is resulting in 8-12 seconds of API down time for us while new http requests continue to be routed to the now-stopped tasks that are still in the target group. This happens now whether we trigger the service update via the CLI or the console - same behaviour. Shown here are a screenshot showing a sample sequence of Events from ECS demonstrating the issue as well as the corresponding ECS agent logs for the same instance.

[image: ECS task events showing task stopped before removal from target group]

[image: ECS agent logs showing more detailed agent activity]

Of particular note when reviewing these ECS agent logs against the sequence of events is that *the logs do not have an entry at 21:04:50 when the task was stopped*. This feels like a clue to me, but I'm not sure where to go from here with it. Has anyone experienced something like this, or have any insights as to why the tasks wouldn't drain and be removed from the target group before being stopped?

For reference, the service is behind an AWS application load balancer. Happy to provide additional details if someone thinks of what else may be relevant

Comment: What is your Minimum Healthy Percent, and Maximum Healthy Percent settings in the ECS service configuration?

Comment: minimum 60%, maximum 200%

Comment: What about the Deregistration Delay setting?

Comment: the deregistration delay is 300 seconds

Comment: That's really strange. I would try setting Minimum Healthy Percent to 100%. Are you using something like Terraform or CloudFormation, which would make it easy to find changes in your infrastructure between the time it was working and the time it stopped working? Otherwise you might need to file an AWS support ticket, because your deployments don't appear to be respecting your deployment settings.

Comment: I am using TF, that's a good point, I'll review the history there. I'll also try the 100% minimum, also a good thought. Yeah, that's what I was afraid of, it's just not appealing to have to add 3% to our spend across _everything_ to fix one sub-service should be working that we're already paying for anyway, but that may just have to be what happens. Appreciate your help Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that ECS changed the timing of when the events would be logged in the UI in the screenshot. In fact, the targets *were* actually being drained before being stopped. The "stopped *n* running task(s)" message is now logged at the beginning of the task shutdown lifecycle steps (before deregistration) instead of at the end (after deregistration) like it used to.

That said, we were still getting brief downtime spikes on our service at the load balancer level during deployments, but ultimately this turned out to be because of the high startup overhead on the new versions of the tasks spinning up briefly pegging the CPU of the instances in the cluster to 100% when there was also sufficient taffic happening during the deployment, thus causing some requests to get dropped.

A good-enough for now solution was to adjust our minimum healthy deployment percentage up to 100% **and** set the maximum deployment percentage to 150% (as opposed to the old 200% setting), which forces the deployments to "slow down", only launching 50% of the intended new tasks at a time and waiting until they are stable before launching the rest. This spreads out the high task startup overhead to two smaller CPU spikes rather than one large one and has so far successfully prevented any more downtime during deployments. We'll also be looking into reducing the startup overhead itself. Figured I'd update this in case it helps anyone else out there.